# How to use the same controller with an Angular Material dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material within my project. I use many dialogs (just for alert purposes), but I now require quite a complex dialog.

This is the example that the Angular Material site uses:

```
function showDialog($event) {
  var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
  $mdDialog.show({
    parent: parentEl,
    targetEvent: $event,
    template: '<md-dialog aria-label="List dialog">' +
      '  <md-dialog-content>' +
      '    <md-list>' +
      '      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">' +
      '       <p>Number {{item}}</p>' +
      '      ' +
      '    </md-list-item></md-list>' +
      '  </md-dialog-content>' +
      '  <md-dialog-actions>' +
      '    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
      '      Close Dialog' +
      '    </md-button>' +
      '  </md-dialog-actions>' +
      '</md-dialog>',
    locals: {
      items: $scope.items
    },
    controller: DialogController
  });

  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, items) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Instead, would be it possible to not reference a `controller` for the `$mdDialog`, and to just allow it to use the same controller where it was called from?

For example, if it is called via this button, the dialog would simply use the `MyCtrl` controller so that the dialog can access the scope variables.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <md-button ng-click="showDialog($event)" class="md-raised">
    Custom Dialog
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Is this a possibility? Or must I continually use the `locals` property along with broadcasting to keep passing variables back and forth?

Comment: use parent Controller name : $mdDialog.show({
                  controller: MyCtrl                });

Comment: @Sandeep - But wouldn't that create a new instance of that controller? Therefore creating a new scope for that dialog?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do that if you use `controllerAs`. I am doing it with es6 like that:

```
this.$mdDialog.show({
  targetEvent: event,
  templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html',
  controller: () => this,
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
});
```

Without es6 it will look like this:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {
    var self = this;

    this.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: function () {
                return self;
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
        });
    };
});
```

I modified the basic usage example from the docs:
http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/gPvdPp

Comment: Very nice approach. Works well.

Comment: I dindn't know this options. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great approach.. Many Thanks...!!